# Disabling two-finger scrolling in Vim

Tags: vim, scroll, text-cursor

While using Vim(*`v7.3.353-2` at the time of writing*), it's frustrating and time-consuming if my palm accidentally touches the trackpad while resting my hands on the keyboard and causes a scroll in Vim that alters my cursor's position.

How to disable this behaviour?

Comment: do you use the mouse for any purpose in vim? Do you run vim or gvim?

Comment: just vim, actually. But, not really. I use it to select between shell tabs (I use yakuake), but that's the only thing I really need it for when in terminal.

Comment: can you try `set mouse=` (empty) in your vimrc?

Comment: hmm...nothing still. Here, I'll post my .vimrc.
http://pastebin.com/yH01VTU5

Comment: try running `set mouse=` on bufEnter.

Answer (score 4):

You can remap those bindings to a no-operation (see `:help <scrollwheel`:

```
noremap <ScrollWheelUp>      <nop>
noremap <S-ScrollWheelUp>    <nop>
noremap <C-ScrollWheelUp>    <nop>
noremap <ScrollWheelDown>    <nop>
noremap <S-ScrollWheelDown>  <nop>
noremap <C-ScrollWheelDown>  <nop>
noremap <ScrollWheelLeft>    <nop>
noremap <S-ScrollWheelLeft>  <nop>
noremap <C-ScrollWheelLeft>  <nop>
noremap <ScrollWheelRight>   <nop>
noremap <S-ScrollWheelRight> <nop>
noremap <C-ScrollWheelRight> <nop>
```

Comment: Hmm, that didn't work for some reason. Is there any reason in particular why?

Comment: @Holland: what is your vim version?

Comment: @Holland: don't accept my answer if it did not work for you. Questions with accepted answers have lower probability of getting other answers. I thought that you might have an older version of vim but I was wrong. Then I am afraid I don't know how to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a problem with your terminal program.  I just tried yakuake and it looks like its some variant on KDE's konsole.  There is an open bug on this:

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=170582

Perhaps naively, I hope that fixing this bug for konsole will also fix the behaviour for yakuake.